# Xamarin.Forms throws an InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Every time I create a new Xamarin.Forms Blank XAML Project it throws an Unhandled Exception when running the Android platform:

"Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"

Notice that to reproduce this issue it's not necessary to add code or views. Just create a project and execute in an Android platform.

I'm deploying in a Samsung tablet with Android 5.1 - API 22

My development environment is:

- Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3:

  - Xamarin 4.2.2.11
  - Xamarin.Android 7.0.2.42
- JDK 1.8.0.112
- Android NDK r13b

Default Xamarin Forms project includes the following NuGet package versions:

- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.180
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 v23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.* v23.3.0

I was able to solve this error by downgrading Xamarin.Forms from 2.3.3.180 to 2.3.3.168

I would like to know why this is happening and whether its a bug or wrong versions installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue yesterday. You need to make sure you have a theme set in the Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" package="yourpackage" android:versionCode="0" android:versionName="Alpha">
```

More info: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41380

Comment: Your soultion didn't work for me.

Also, I've had a look to the link you suggest. It indicates how to solve it, but it doesn't help to know why it happens.

Comment: From my understanding it happens in the upgrade to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms. Until you find the fix it will be hard to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: Old question, but FWIW I got this one resolved by the good ol' get rid of obj/bin in my Android project